# Jquery console value not return any value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, console.log

Hello every one i have small clarification in my project

in my project console.log() function return no values.

```
<script>
$('#search-box<?=$x;?>').blur(function() {
        var val = $("#search-list<?=$x;?>").val();
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "searchlist.php",
             data:'amount='+$(this).val(),
             success: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            var o_val = $("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val(data);
            var number = $('#quantity<?=$x;?>').val();
            console.log(o_val);

            }
         });
             });
</script>
```

here console.log(data); Values can display.

`var o_val = $("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val(data);` whenever i will assign the varible and showing that varible in console it is not working

```
console.log(o_val);
```

My Console Output is look like this 
`console.log(data)`----> 245 `</br>`

```
var o_val = $("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val(data); ---> n.fn.init [input#unit_pricea1.form-control.unit_pricea1, context: document, selector: "#unit_pricea1"]
```

Comment: $("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val(data) not return any value. Hence it is not displaying.

Comment: here $x for for loop function

Comment: Correct only. The element #unit_pricea is shown.... if you want o_val  -> 245 then u should use console.log($("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val()). But this wont work and throw error because u are using console.log javascript command with <?= $x; ?> (what is this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you set the value using `$(selector).val(data)`, it returns the DOM selector instead of the value.

If you want the value to be returned then you should use val():

```
$("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val(data);
var o_val = $("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val();
console.log(o_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value to the variable o_val, then you can print.

```
var o_val=data;
console.log(o_val);
```